# Control buffering in VideoView

Tags: android, streaming, video-streaming, android-videoview

I'm trying to use a VideoView to display a mp4 video from Vimeo. Everything works fine but is there a way that I can control the buffering of the video? My problem is that I have 6 VideoView's in one view and as soon as the view loads all of them starts buffering right away. I would like them to only start buffering when i press play on one of them to lower internet usage.

Is there a way to start/stop the buffering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stop auto buffer in VideoView android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834659/stop-auto-buffer-in-videoview-android)

Answer (score 0):

For your case: The VideoView wraps the MediaPlayer, making it unable to control the buffering. You would have to recreate the "VideoView" by taking a surface and a MediaPlayer, then calling PrepareAsync on the latter. Refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45834659/stop-auto-buffer-in-videoview-android/45835882#45835882) for more details.

Comment: If it is a duplicate, you should flag it as such and post as an answer imo.

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't know how to do this, now i learned it, thanks!